# Files moved with SPFile.MoveTo require a full crawl to be searchable

Tags: 2013, search, event-receivers, spfile

We've got a problem in our search-driven document management system, and I'm running out of ideas.

A custom event receiver, on `ItemUpdated()` checks to see if the files metadata requires it to be moved to another library (in the same `SPWeb`). If so, it creates any required folders, moves it with `SPFile.MoveTo()`, then updates another bit of metadata with `SPFile.Item.Update()` and followed up with `SPList.Update()` (which may or may not be necessary).

Sometimes the event receiver fires immediately after the file is added (by a very complex timer job we would prefer not to re-write), but it is also run when changes are made to metadata by users.

The problem is that the search indexer will not pick up the changes until a full crawl is run. We run continuous crawls and are dependant on having up to date search results. Until now we've been running three extra full crawls each day, but as the volume of files grows this is becoming impractical.

How should we move the files so that an incremental crawl will find the changes?

P.s. This is an on-premise SP2013 farm.

Comment: Tyr, make sure the moved files are checked-in and published.

Comment: @Naveen: the library in question doesn't use versioning, but they are definitely checked in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm grasping at straws here, there isn't a lot of information on the topic about this. I did stumble upon a post that may give clues as to why it is happening and perhaps a work around:

> SPFile.MoveTo(), at first glance, looks to be a very straightforward
>   method where a file can be moved from one folder to another.
>
> Trying to use it and have an alert triggered by your newly copied
>   file? Forget it.
>
> MoveTo() copies the binary to the target library as expected, but
>   fails to recreate the item metadata (created, modified, users, dates,
>   etc.) and will not trigger the alerts that your users set up for the
>   target library.
>
> To work around this problem, you can create your own method that uses
>   the SPFileCollection.Add(), which allows you to specify metadata, as
>   described here: (broken link ommitted).

http://sharepointers.blogspot.com/2009/01/spfilemoveto-not-triggering-alerts-in.html

If this is the case, then I can see why it wouldn't be found until a full crawl is run.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like it might be the answer, however it throws up another problem. When previously using SPFileCollection.Add() in a content organiser ICustomRouter implementation, I was unable to get it to accept the modified and created times. There is an overload which takes parameters for them, but no matter what I did it would ignore their values and use the current time instead. We need to preserve at least the created time on the moved file, which SPFile.Move() does.

Comment: Couldn't you update the values in another operation after it was moved in that case? Or try a SPFile.CopyTo(), since it is in the same web, then delete the source document?